# multivalue or array indexing in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'd like to know a bit more about the next situation. I'm trying to index a document like this:

```
PUT 'server/index/test/1'
{
    to: "to1",
    to: "to2",
    to: "to3"
}
```

Seemingly, elasticsearch swallows this document. Ok , no problem. Nevertheless, I would like to know which are the differences between an array of values.

How the searches are made?

**EDITED:**

I've tried this searches:

```
GET 'server/index/test/_search?q=to:to1&pretty'
GET 'server/index/test/_search?q=to:to2&pretty'
GET 'server/index/test/_search?q=to:to3&pretty'
```

and ES shows me the document after each execution:

```
{
   "took" : 44,
   "timed_out" : false,
   "_shards" : {
       "total" : 5,
       "successful" : 5,
       "failed" : 0
   },
   "hits" : {
   "total" : 1,
   "max_score" : 1.0,
       "hits" : [ {
           "_index" : "index",
           "_type" : "test",
           "_id" : "1",
           "_score" : 1.0,
           "_source":
           {
               to: "to1",
               to: "to2",
               to: "to3"
           }
       } ]
    }
}
```

Seemingly, ES indexes every repeated field value also... Is it really like this? Or I'm performing or doing something wrong?

Comment: You're indexing the document into the `server` index, but the response somehow shows that the document is in the `living` index. Weird, not sure how that's possible.

Comment: It's just a typing mistake. I've just edited it. `server` means the url to ES server, that's not the index. The index is `index`, and the collection is `test`

Comment: Ok, makes sense. What still doesn't make sense, though, is your `source` with `to` fields which are not even double-quoted strings. Which tool/plugin are you using to send your queries?

Comment: I'm using `curl` tool.

Comment: Interesting case. Using Sense, I get a `Bad string` (next to the first `to` field) warning when retrieving the search results...

Answer (score 1):

In a JSON document you cannot have two fields with the same name, but ES will silently "fix" your document and only index a single `to` field. Moreover, since a JSON document is basically a map, which is inherently unordered, you have no guarantee as to which one of the three `to` fields get indexed.

So if you index that document, it will work, but you'll only see a single `to` field in it, which is probably **not what you want**:

```
PUT 'server/test/1'
{
    to: "to1",
    to: "to2",
    to: "to3"
}

GET 'server/test/1'
{
    to: "to3"            <--- could also be to1 or to2
}
```

However, if you make `to` an array of values then all the values will be indexed

```
PUT 'server/test/1'
{
    to: ["to1", "to2", "to3"]
}

GET 'server/test/1'
{
    to: ["to1", "to2", "to3"]
}
```

Comment: I've added some searches on my post. It seems ES indexes every repeated field value?